# Moving Emails to subfolder with Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, csv, outlook

I am trying to write the sender/subject info of all the emails in my outlook inbox to a csv file and then move the emails to a subfolder of my inbox (called "After") using Powershell. The CSV file is created correctly with the email info, but only the first half + 1 emails are actually moved to the subfolder. Here is my code:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6;
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox);
$inbox.items|Select SenderEmailAddress,subject|Export-Csv C:\Scripts\Testing.csv -NoTypeInformation;
ForEach ($Item in $inbox.items){
    try{
        $Item.Move($inbox.Folders.Item("After")) | out-null;
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Failed to move item", $Item.Id.UniqueId;
    }
}
```

This is my first time using Powershell so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Move() changes the collection. Use a down "for" loop (from items.Count down to 1) instead of "foreach".

Comment: So "ForEach ($Item in $inbox.items)" should be For($i=0; $i -le $inbox.Count; $i++)?

Comment: No, you need to go from Items.Count down to 1. Keep in mind that all Outlook collections are 1 based, not 0.

Comment: So For ($i=($inbox.items.count-1);$i -ge 0;$i--)? Also, I am seeing that Move-item cmdlet is better than $_.move(). Is that something I should be using instead?

Comment: For ($i=($inbox.items.count);$i -ge 1;$i--)?

Comment: It would also be a great idea to cache the value of Inbox.Items before entering the loop instead of using the multiple dot notation.